# Minimal size of a generating set for presentations of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Are there any results on the minimal number of generators required to give a presentation of a finite group? More specifically, given a group G, what is the minimal number of generators needed for a presentation of it? No bounds on the number of relations are assumed.

I've not found anything after doing some research.

Comment: Well, it depends on what the group is.  Are there any specific cases you are interested in?

Comment: This is the same as asking about the minimal number of generators for a group - presentations are not particularly relevant. This is a much studied question. For example it is known that all finite simple groups can be generated by two elements.

Comment: The direct product of $n$ copies of the cyclic group of order $p$ prime, $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$, cannot be generated by fewer than $n$ elements (via a basic vector space argument).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is the simple result that it can't possibly require more generators than the number of prime factors in the group order (counted with multiplicity).